# Comparar la diferencia de 2 Fechas

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Tengo mi fecha guardada en tabla "contacto_fechas", "21-01-2010 mostrada asi:

```
{{date('d-m-y', strtotime($Contacto_fechas1->diaContactoFecha))}}
```

y la fecha actual

```
{{$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now() }}
o lo que es lo mismo
<?php $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now(); ?>
mi fecha actual
{{$mytime->toDateString()}}
```

mi pregunta es si con algo similar a:

```
@if ((diaContactoFecha - 30 dias) =< $mytime)
<font color="red">{{$mytime->toDateString()}}</font> en rojo
@else
 {{$mytime->toDateString()}} normal
@endif
```

puedo comparar la fecha actual contra la fecha registrada menos 30 dias y imprimirla de otro color mientras se cumpla la condicion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedo recomendarte que evites el uso de funciones complejas en tu vista, dicha lógica debe estar en el controlador y luego pasar los datos a la vista, aquí te voy a poner un ejemplo:

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($diaContactoFecha)->sub(new \DateInterval('P30D')) <= Carbon\Carbon::now())
  <font color="red">{{$mytime->toDateString()}}</font> en rojo
@else
  {{$mytime->toDateString()}} normal
@endif
```

Carbon tiene una función llamada **sub** con la cual puedes hacer una resta pasandole un intervalo, el formato empleado en este código *P30D* la P significa period es el comienzo del intervalo, un prefijo que siempre va, el 30 es para indicar un valor en nuestro caso es la cantidad de dias que quieres substraer y la *D* es para decir que ese valor representan los dias, la *M* son los meses, la *Y* son los años, y si deseas restar intervalos de tiempo debes añadir una *T* y la representación de las horas, los minutos y los segundos no es dificil de adivinar :P

Si todo esto lo hicieses del lado de la controladora quedaria algo como:

```
@if ($perteneceAlMesPasado) 
  .....
@else
  .....
```

Y en tu controladora dirias:

```
$perteneceAlMesPasado = Carbon\Carbon::parse($diaContactoFecha)->sub(new \DateInterval('P30D')) <= Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! si aun soy muy nuevo en laravel y tengo las malas costumbres que van saliendo por tener que entregar lo antes posible, implemente y funciono exelente , y estoy implementando en el controlador apenas. muchas gracias